# Desktop restarts loop In vertical

Tags: windows-10, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Desktop fails to start, bios screen then restarts loop, or keeps power turning off and on.

When kept horizontal pc seems to start, and keep running. What's the explanation for this ? Loose cpu heatsink ? Needs thermal paste ? Or shorting the entire motherboard somehow and psu keeps shutting power ?

Shutdown was modified or some new process files were created in an attack few days ago. After that processor fan speed is low, is it possible to hack the device firmwares ?

Comment: Sounds like something physical.  Something is loose and shifts when you move the chassis.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop for a proper diagnosis.

Comment: I want to say 'turn the machine sideways and move on' but that isn't funny.  Honestly.. I would pull and reseat everything in the box.. blowing it out while I went.  This includes cables.  You will probably find that the problem goes away.  If you aren't comfortable doing this, follow @DavidPostill advice.

Comment: Try clearing the cmos.